# Switch wordpress widget by page shortcode

Tags: wordpress, plugins, widget, shortcode

I am creating a plugin that contains a widget and a shortcode for the page content. Now I want to be able to disable the widget (or change it content) when a page with my shortcode is used.

It looks like the widget code is loaded before the page.. so is this even possible?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like this is not possible. I fixed it by adding an option to my widget where the user has to set the page it should not be visible.

and make a simple switch in de widget code:

```
   $currentPage = get_the_ID();
   if($notToShowPage != $currentPage){      
        //code
   }
```